# Conv2D filters and CNN architecture

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, mnist

I am currently pursuing undergraduation, I am working on CNN model to recognize Telegu characters.

This Questions has two parts,

1. I have a (32,32,1) shape Telegu character images, I want to train my CNN model to recognize the character. So, what should be my model architecture and how to decide the architecture, no of parameters and hidden layers. I know that my case is exactly same as handwritten digit recognition, but I want to know how to decide those parameters. Is there any common practice in building such architecture.
2. Operation Conv2D (32, (5,5)) means 32 filters of size 5x5 are applied on to the input, my question is are these filters all same or different, if different what kind of filters are initialized and who decides them?

I tried to surf internet but everywhere I go, the answer I get is Conv2D operation applies filters on input and does the convolution operation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To decide which model architecture would be best, you need to experiment. Thats the only way. As you want to classify, VGG architecture would be a good starting point I believe. You need to experiment with number of parameters as it depends on your problem. You can use Keras Tuner for it: https://keras.io/keras_tuner/
For kernel initialization, as far as I know convolutional layers in Keras uses Glorot Uniform Initialization but you can change that by using `kernel_initializer` parameter. Long story short, convolutional layers are initialized with a distribution function and as training goes filters change the values inside, which is learning process. https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers
Edit: I forgot to inform you that I suggest VGG architecture but in a way you downsize the models a lot. Your input shape is little so if your model is too much deep, you will overfit really quickly.